# forEach method doesn't set a boolean type properly in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'm having a simple function where inside I'm trying to set some boolean value for either false or true. The boolean value always stars as false, but when inside the forEach method it should be set to true - the problem seems weirder because in the forEach method there is an "if-statement" which cheks whether the boolean should be set to true or suppose to be left as false. Looking at the code should be more comprehensive - the problem itself seems trivial.

Not much to do here actually - I've tried some code tweaking but none of this worked.

```
exists: boolean; //here's the variable declaration at the beginning of the class

onCreateFolder(nodeId) { //the actual function

this.exists = false;

this.nodeService.getNodeChildren(nodeId).forEach(
  node => {
    node.list.entries.forEach(
      actualNode => {
        if(actualNode.entry.isFolder && actualNode.entry.name === theName) {
          this.exists = true;
          this.existingFolderId = actualNode.entry.id;
          console.log("Found the existing folder! " + this.existingFolderId); //console log is beeing printed - so the if statement is true at least once so as this.exists should be set to true
        }
      }
    )
  }
)

//after leaving the method above the it seems like this.exists goes back to false(?)

  if(!this.exists) {

  //always get into

  } else if(this.exists) {

  //never get into

  }


}
```

The if statement in forEach methods above is true - the console log about finding the actual folder is beeing printed so as "this.exists" - should be set as true but when it leaves - there is latter if and else if statements and it seems like "this.exists" always is false.

Comment: Is `this.nodeService.getNodeChildren` async?

Comment: Probably the .forEach function of the object returned by .getNodeChildren(..) captures a different context for 'this', even beyond TypeScripts automatic capturing of 'this' in arrow functions during transpiling. Can't reproduce, because I don't know from which library .getNodeChildren originates. But try to see if 'this' within the .forEach is actually your class. If not, capture it before calling the .forEach (e.g. let self = this;)

Comment: Not sure wheter it's async - I changed the outer "forEach" - to subscribe method. Here's some doc: https://www.alfresco.com/abn/adf/docs/tutorials/working-with-nodes-api-service/ @Karim Ayachi - "this" is actual "this" - I tried something with "let self = this" - but the results have been the same.

Comment: According to the documentation you posted, the return type of .getNodeChildren is an Observable (http://reactivex.io/documentation/observable.html) of type NodeList. So I think @VLAZ is right. If you place a console.log() just before the if(!this.exists) you should get a clue from the order of the logs in your console. I would suggest wrapping all your code into the subscribe. But I don't know Alfresco and can't test it here, so it's a bit of a guess...